# Counting classes from an external page with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript file that needs to count how many classes (.wrapper) there are in a external html page.

So far i have been using this for a count (it was previously all on the same page).

```
var adCount = $('.wrapper').size();
alert(adCount);
```

But i can't seem to find anything that would allow me to run this statement on a different page than the code is runing on. I was hoping to add something like this.

```
var adCount = $('js/sliderExternal.html .wrapper').size();
alert(adCount);
```

They are in the same directory but I'm keeping the pages seperate as the external page needs to be updated constantly and i don't want it in the middle of a page of code. (This page may be updated by people who don't code at all). Anyway, any help on this would be much appreciated.

If you need any more information ask away!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
$.get('js/sliderExternal.html', function(data){
  $(data).find('.wrapper').size();
})
```

Also see [API Doc for $.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/).

Comment: Thanks, you got me over the 5'000 reputation mark. Made my day! :)

Comment: Get in! I can only hope to reach that score. One day at a time. :)

Comment: That should get you started ;) Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

You would have to load the page into your html first using `document.load()` and `append()` it to your DOM structure. Once you do this you can use JQuery to find the number of classes within it.

Answer (score 0):

Load that external html inside some `div` having visibility false.something like this:

```
  $('#id_of_div').load(external_url)
```

and then find the length using:

```
   var numItems = $('.wrapper').length
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Milind Anantwar, I've gone with PiTheNumber's response, but i can see yours working also, thanks for the time.